# Using JavaScript to get RadGrid for print

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I'm creating a print function and the key is to call the grid that I want to print. It has been working well if the grid is existing on the aspx page, until when I also need to print a list of RadGrids that are generated programmatically behind the code then JavaScript cannot detect these non-existing grids and return the error of "the control does not exist". Just to be clear, it's not working because at the time when I'm typing the code, there's no RadGrid_Dynamic on the page, hence erroring. There's nothing to do with when the page execute/page life cycle etc.

My work around is to try to call the control by string value, as using

`$find('<%= RadGrid_Dynamic.ClientID %>')`,

the page will highlight RadGrid_Dynamic and say it doesn't exists as mentioned above. Below is my code, I've also tried replacing the `$find()` with `document.getElementById()`, but no luck, any advice? Thanks.

```
function getOuterHTML(obj) {
    if (typeof (obj.outerHTML) == "undefined") {
        var divWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        var copyOb = obj.cloneNode(true);
        divWrapper.appendChild(copyOb);
        return divWrapper.innerHTML
    }
    else {
        return obj.outerHTML;
    }
}
function Print() {

    var previewWindow = window.open('about:blank', '', '', false);
    var styleSheet = '<%= Telerik.Web.SkinRegistrar.GetWebResourceUrl(this, RadGrid1.GetType(), String.Format("Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.{0}.Grid.{0}.css", RadGrid1.Skin)) %>';
    var baseStyleSheet = '<%= Telerik.Web.SkinRegistrar.GetWebResourceUrl(this, RadGrid1.GetType(), "Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.Grid.css") %>';
    var htmlContent = "<html><head><link href = '" + styleSheet + "' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></link>";
    htmlContent += "<link href = '" + baseStyleSheet + "' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></link></head><body>";
    for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        var CYGrid = "RadGrid_CY_Strategy_" + String(i);
        var CYradGrid = $find('<%=CYGrid.ClientID %>'); //Highlighted as red and erorr: The Name 'CYGird' does not exist in the current content

        var LYGrid = "RadGrid_LY_" + String(i);
        var LYradGrid = $find('<%=LYGrid.ClientID %>'); //Ditto

        htmlContent += getOuterHTML(CYradGrid.get_element());
        if (LYradGrid.hidden == false) {
            htmlContent += getOuterHTML(LYradGrid.get_element());
        }
    }
    htmlContent += "</body></html>";
    previewWindow.document.open();
    previewWindow.document.write(htmlContent);
    previewWindow.document.close();
    previewWindow.print();

    if (!$telerik.isChrome) {
        previewWindow.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could programmatically assign an ID to the dynamic grid when it's being created and use that ID to do a `$find()`.